# template function with method signature

Tags: c++, templates

I know it is possible to achieve something like this:

```
template<typename T_Signature>
class FooBar;

template<typename T_Return, typename ... T_Params>
class FooBar<T_Return(T_Params ...)>
{
    ... 
};
```

However, plain functions don't support (partial) specialization. Is it still possible to get the same effect? E.g:

```
std::function<void(int,std::string)> x = function_proxy<void(int,std::string)>(&some_func);
```

What i want to do is have a plain (in namespace/global) function (->not contained in any class or other structure) that takes a function signature as template argument.

Comment: You forgot `...` in `class FooBar<T_Return(T_Params...)>`

Comment: Perhaps you want to add more details to your question

Comment: Actually you do not partially specialize function here just the class and this is fully supported in c++

Comment: i know i can achieve it with classes, like shown above. however, i want to achive the same using plain functions.

Comment: `template <typename T> void function_proxy(T) {}` would suffice, since `T` will be adjusted to a function pointer type

Comment: And if you really need partial specialization you can always use class specialization and overload bracket operator...

Answer (score 0):

A function signature is just a type.  So you can take it no problem.

If you want to unpack it to get at its constituant types, or only take function signatures and not other types, you have to do more work.  Stuff like a traits class "is signature" and helpers to extract the arg count, the return value and the arguments (maybe as a tuple type).

It won't work like the specialization case.